# has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many_through between the same models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a model `person` and a model `group`. There are two kinds of persons: leaders lead a group and participants participate. I need a hbtm-relationship between leaders and groups and a has_many-relationship between participants and groups. Is it possible to do this with the same model, `person` by providing some kind of condition (is a leader/is a participant) in the model?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :participations
  has_many :groups, :through => :participations
  ...
end
```

I would like to do this with one model, `person`, because users are either leaders or participants but each user should be a person, i.e. `User belongs_to :person`.

Comment: I can understand when a leader has many groups. But are sure that a group has many leaders?

Comment: Yes, my groups can have many leaders. Think of a team of leaders that organizes a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should only one class for persons, not more. You can do something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relations
  has_many :groups, :through => :relations
   ...
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relations
  has_many :persons, :through => :relations
  ...
end

class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :group
end
```

table 'relations' should have next to person_id and group_id, one more field, called, for example 'leader' and the value should be true/false or 1/0. So, if the person of the group is leader, the value should be 1/true, if not then 0/false